# Select array and join in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table and an array of primary keys, and I'd like to join them:

```
select [1, 2, 3] as keys
join my_table t on t.id = ???
```

Obviously this is a simplified example, if it were so simple I would do it with an `in` clause, but let's pretend I'm constrained and need to get this query style to work.

Comment: What results are you expecting from a query like this?

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.my_table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'more data' cols UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'even more' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'more'
), primary_keys AS (
  SELECT [1, 2, 3] AS keys
)
SELECT t.*
FROM primary_keys
JOIN `project.dataset.my_table` t 
ON t.id IN UNNEST(keys)
```

with output

```
Row id  cols     
1   1   more data    
2   3   even more
```